# how insert how many post type in this function?

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I have two type post and i want display both in tag. this function i can insert one post type, how insert two post type in this function

```
function post_type_tags_fix($request) {
    if ( isset($request['tag']) && !isset($request['post_type']) )
    $request['post_type'] = 'any';
    return $request;
} 
add_filter('request', 'post_type_tags_fix');
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) instead of `request`:

```
function post_type_tags_fix( $request ) {
    if ( ! is_admin()
         && $request->is_tag()
         && $request->is_main_query() ) {
             $request->set( 'post_type', array( 'type_one', 'type_two' ) )
    }
} 
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'post_type_tags_fix' );
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I insert post type but dont work.

Comment: update your question with the names of your post types and what you've tried.

Comment: function post_type_tags_fix( $request ) {
    if ( ! is_admin()
         && $request->is_tag()
         && $request->is_main_query() ) {
             $request->set( 'post_type', array( 'eg', 'portfolio' ) )
    }
} 
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'post_type_tags_fix' );

Comment: [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/228044/edit), not in a comment. where have you placed this code? is your tag template using the standard loop?

Comment: in function.php .